# PIVOT on TWO Aggregates

Tags: sql, t-sql

```
SELECT * FROM 
            (
              SELECT ID,
                     CODE,
                     CAST(SUM(QTY) AS INT) AS G_QTY,
                     CAST(SUM(Amount) AS INT) AS AmountUsed
              FROM Tbl_Used
              WHERE CODE IN ('ABC','DEF','GHI')
              GROUP BY ID,CODE
            ) AS S
PIVOT
   (
    SUM(AmountUsed) 
    FOR CODE IN(ABC,DEF)
    ) AS Pivot1
```

I also want to PIVOT the G_QTY for CODE IN ('GHI')

Results should be:

```
ID  ABC DEF GHI
1   10  20  30
```

TABLE DATA

```
ID  CODE    QTY AMOUNT
1122    ABC 546 789653
456     GHI 5644    65433213
1455    DEF 99978   464646
1122    ABC 6565    98464
1455    DEF 88933   7933
2454    GHI 88989   5522
456     ABC 108309  789653
2454    DEF 125414  65433213
4452    GHI 142519  464646
3120    GHI 159624  98464
456     GHI 176729  7933
3120    ABC 193834  5522
456     GHI 210938  125414
4452    DEF 228043  142519
1455    ABC 245148  159624
3120    DEF 262253  176729
```

The data is not real but similar to production environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have rewrote the query. So that there is not need for two pivot and also because the pivot already aggregates and group by the inner query is not needed.

So my suggestion is the following:

**Test data**

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT,CODE VARCHAR(5),QTY INT, AMOUNT INT)
INSERT INTO @tbl
VALUES
(1122,'ABC',546,789653),
(456,'GHI',5644,65433213),
(1455,'DEF',99978,464646),
(1122,'ABC',6565,98464),
(1455,'DEF',88933,7933),
(2454,'GHI',88989,5522),
(456,'ABC',108309,789653),
(2454,'DEF',125414,65433213),
(4452,'GHI',142519,464646),
(3120,'GHI',159624,98464),
(456,'GHI',176729,7933),
(3120,'ABC',193834,5522),
(456,'GHI',210938,125414),
(4452,'DEF',228043,142519),
(1455,'ABC',245148,159624),
(3120,'DEF',262253,176729)
```

**Query**

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        tbl.ID,
        tbl.CODE,
        (
            CASE 
                WHEN tbl.CODE='GHI' 
                THEN QTY 
                ELSE Amount
            END
        ) AS ValueToPivot
    FROM 
        @tbl AS tbl
    WHERE tbl.CODE IN ('ABC','DEF','GHI')
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
    SUM(ValueToPivot)
    FOR CODE IN ([ABC],[DEF],[GHI])
) AS pvt
```

This will get you the result:

```
ID      ABC     DEF         CHI
------------------------------------
456     789653  NULL        393311
1122    888117  NULL        NULL
1455    159624  472579      NULL
2454    NULL    65433213    88989
3120    5522    176729      159624
4452    NULL    142519      142519
```

Comment: I had to add the GROUP BY in the inner query as I am using SUM in the SELECT statement. This query has worked. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @VigneshKumar : yes it yields the same result. But if you are looking at the query plan by comparing the queries. Then I would expect that my query is fast then yours. I just simplified the query not to have an inner aggregation and an additional pivot which was not needed.

Comment: @VigneshKumar , using the test data, your answer gives me the same result, but in production I am getting values equal to column names

Comment: @VigneshKumar this may have something to do with the MAX function

Answer (score 2):

May be something like this:

```
SELECT ID,Max(ABC) AS ABC,Max(DEF) As DEF,Max(GHI) AS GHI
FROM 
   (
    SELECT ID,
           CODE,
           CODE As CODE1,
           CAST(SUM(QTY) AS INT) AS G_QTY,
           CAST(SUM(Amount) AS INT) AS AmountUsed
    FROM Tbl_Used
    WHERE CODE IN ('ABC','DEF','GHI')
    GROUP BY ID,CODE
    ) AS S
PIVOT
    (
    SUM(AmountUsed) 
    FOR CODE IN([ABC],[DEF])
    ) AS Pivot1
PIVOT
    (
    SUM(G_QTY) 
    FOR CODE1 IN([GHI])
    ) AS Pivot2

Group By ID
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/43428/4)**

---

*Output:*

```
ID      ABC     DEF     GHI
456     789653  (null)  393311
1122    888117  (null)  (null)
1455    159624  472579  (null)
2454    (null)  65433213 88989
3120    5522    176729  159624
4452    (null)  142519  142519
```

Comment: I tried that using Pivot1 and Pivot2 but on the line for Pivot2 {Invalid column name CODE}, it seems you can't use a column more than once